# Geometry Nodes: How to select instances either side of an index?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I have a geometry nodes setup that instances a set of cards along a curve, and turns each card over as a 'completed' value is increased from 0 to 100. However, my setup only turns one card over at once, which given the number of cards I'm using means that unless I'm using motion blur, it's difficult to tell that the cards are flipping, as they look like they're just snapping from one rotational value to another.

Is there a way to begin turning the cards either side of the selected index at the same time so for example a card 3 in front of the index will begin turning, the index will be at the midpoint in it's turn, and the card 3 behind the index will be finishing it's turn?

My current nodes setup:

[image: Geometry nodes setup]

.blend file:
[image]

Many thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: Thanks Rick - I've added the .blend file now. <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to work it out by feeding the index into a subtract node (set to 7), and then feeding the index and the subtract node into a map range node, which then feeds into the mix factor of the node controlling the angle of rotation.

I've attached the blend here for anyone wanting to achieve the same effect.

[image]

[image: cards flipping]